# Use JS to match elements by id with different parents (on hover)

Tags: javascript, html, hover

My JS skills are failing me, and maybe also my Google skills. This is what I'm trying to do:

When an `<li>` is hovered in the .first division, add an ".active" class to the `<li>` in the .second division with the same ID. So if you hover over .first li#one, a class of .active would be added .second li#one.

*Note: the IDs are dynamic and so can't be known in advance.*

Here's what the html would look like:

```html
<div class"first">
  
  <ul>
    <li id="one">Lorem</li>
    <li id="two">Ipsum</li>
    <li id="three">Dolor</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>

<div class="second">

  <ul>
    <li id="one">Lorem</li>
    <li id="two">Ipsum</li>
    <li id="three">Dolor</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

I don't think there's a pure CSS solution, but of course that would be even better.

Anyone looking to do this with classes instead of IDs, here's the edited snippet from the below answer:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("nav.primary li").forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.${e.target.classList}`)[1].classList.add("active");
  });
  li.addEventListener("mouseout", e => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.${e.target.classList}`)[1].classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: I know IDs shouldn't be duplicated. I just meant this as an example, but maybe I could simplify things by making the ids in the second div slightly different. For example, id="second-one", id="second-two", and etc.

Terrible naming, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are CSS solutions for things like this, such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-one-element-is-hovered).

However, because you said you won't know the IDs of the elements in advance, JavaScript seems like a fair choice. I'm not saying it's impossible with CSS, but my solution uses JavaScript.

Basically you can loop through all of the `<li>` elements contained within the `first` class and apply two event listeners. One for `mouseover` and one for `mouseout` (*hover*). From here, the script selects the second instance of an element with the same id and adds or removes a class `active`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".first ul li").forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener("mouseover", e => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`#${e.target.id}`)[1].classList.add("active");
  });
  li.addEventListener("mouseout", e => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`#${e.target.id}`)[1].classList.remove("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.active { background: #CCC; }
```

```html
<div class="first">
  
  <ul>
    <li id="one">Lorem</li>
    <li id="two">Ipsum</li>
    <li id="three">Dolor</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>

<div class="second">

  <ul>
    <li id="one">Lorem</li>
    <li id="two">Ipsum</li>
    <li id="three">Dolor</li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```